# org.restlet.routing.Router doesn't seem to accept encoded slashes

Tags: java, encoding, restlet

I am using Restlet and am having issues with a Router template whose variable in the template contains encoded slashes.  Here's the details:

When I use this route:

```
/blob/sqlserver/{uniqueid}
```

And pass this (note %2F is /):

```
/blob/sqlserver/Refinance-Other%2FFRM%2F660-700%2F4.00-4.50%2Fproperties-4.00-4.50.csv
```

or this:

```
/blob/sqlserver/Refinance-Other/FRM/660-700/4.00-4.50/properties-4.00-4.50.csv
```

I get a 404

If I use this router:

```
/blob/sqlserver/{purpose}/{type}/{creditscore}/{interestrate}/{file}
```

and pass this:

```
/blob/sqlserver/Refinance-Other/FRM/660-700/4.00-4.50/properties-4.00-4.50.csv
```

It works, but I can't do it this way, because I don't control who is sending me this URI and the variables will change, so it has to be the encoded slashes.

To test this further I also tried this template again:

```
/blob/sqlserver/{uniqueid}
```

but also used the MODE_STARTS_WITH

```
.setMatchingMode(Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
```

When I do that, it does find this:

```
/blob/sqlserver/Refinance-Other/FRM/660-700/4.00-4.50/properties-4.00-4.50.csv
```

But I only get "Refinance-Other" as the variable under uniqueid.

However, the encoded slashes still doesn't work, which seems very odd?  Why would it work for the above non-encoded URI with MODE_STARTS_WITH and not this URI?:

```
/blob/sqlserver/Refinance-Other%2FFRM%2F660-700%2F4.00-4.50%2Fproperties-4.00-4.50.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually ended up that the URL encoding was being decoded before it got to me, these two posts helped me figure this out.  As proof, double encoding worked:

[Is a slash ("/") equivalent to an encoded slash ("%2F") in the path portion of an HTTP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957115/is-a-slash-equivalent-to-an-encoded-slash-2f-in-the-path-portion-of-a)

[ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH on AWS Elasticbeanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231836/allow-encoded-slash-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk)

and look at the first response to this ticket:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-3990

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests on your use case and I work for me with version 2.3.4 of Restlet. Which version did you use?

Here is the code I used:

- **Application**

  ```
  public class RestletApplication extends Application {
      @Override
      public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          Router router = new Router(getContext());
          router.attach("/blob/sqlserver/{uniqueid}", TestServerResource.class);
          return router;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Server resource**

  ```
  public class TestServerResource extends ServerResource {
      @Get
      public String test() {
          String attr = getAttribute("uniqueid");
          System.out.println("attr = "+attr);
          return "ok";
      }
  }
  ```
- **Client**

  ```
  public class TestClient {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
              // Encoded path variable
              ClientResource cr1 = new ClientResource(
                 "http://localhost:8182/blob/sqlserver/Refinance-Other%2FFRM%2F660-700%2F4.00-4.50%2Fproperties-4.00-4.50.csv");
              Representation repr1 = cr1.get();
              System.out.println(repr1.getText());

              // Non encoded path variable
              ClientResource cr2 = new ClientResource(
                  "http://localhost:8182/blob/sqlserver/Refinance-Other/FRM/660-700/4.00-4.50/properties-4.00-4.50.csv");
              Representation repr2 = cr2.get();
              System.out.println(repr2.getText());
          } catch(Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

For the first request, I get a 200 status code and the value of the `uniqueid` path variable is `Refinance-Other%2FFRM%2F660-700%2F4.00-4.50%2Fproperties-4.00-4.50.csv`.

For the second one, I get a 404 status code which is normal since there is no matching route configured in Restlet.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry